# Webpack error when "npm start" on my ReactJS project

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I'm trying to learn ReactJS. I just upgraded my dependencies' versions. I was using "npm start" command always for run my server. When I try that code I'm getting an annoying error like "**webpack 5.65.0 compiled with 2 errors in 769 ms**". I couldn't find my errors. I'm not a real developer. I'm just trying to learn and I'm stuck on this issue.

That's really complicated. So, I just want to uninstall Webpack. You can agree or disagree my idea but Webpack is really annoying. I'm really hate about this stupid thing. I didn't make any changes to my codes. I just updated the version of dependencies. Please help me. I couldn't uninstall Webpack and restore my simple and clear error screen that I am used to.

Comment: If you are using `create-react-app,` don't upgrade the dependencies after the creation of a project. IIRC, there are some breaking changes made in some packages that cause webpack to fail.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried your answer. It's OK for new app. I'm gonna install my all packages again. It's gonna be challenging but worth it.